# Get the x Least Significant Bits from a String in Python

Tags: python, string, character-encoding

How can I get the x LSBs from a string (str) in Python?
In the specific I have a 256 bits string consisting in 32 chars each occupying 1 byte, from which I have to get a "char" string with the 50 Least Significant Bits.

Comment: Not sure, do you have a string `"01101100110"` or do you have a string consisting of 64 chars each occupying 8 bits?

Comment: I have a string consisting of 64 chars each occupying 1 byte.

Comment: As a sidenote, that's actually a 512-bit string (8 bits/ASCII char * 64 ASCII chars = 512 bits.)

Comment: I'm sorry the characters are 32, not 64. 32 * 8  bits = 256 bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a possible answer could be in this function:
`mystr` holds my string

```
def get_lsbs_str(mystr):
    chrlist = list(mystr)
    result1 = [chr(ord(chrlist[-7])&(3))]
    result2 = chrlist[-6:]
    return "".join(result1 + result2)
```

this function take 2 LSBs of the -7rd char of `mystr` (these are the 2 MSBs of the 50 LSBs)
then take the last 6 characters of `mystr` (these are the 48 LSB of the 50 LSB)

Please make me know if I am in error.

Comment: `"".join([chr(ord(list(mystr)[-7])&(3))] + list(mystr)[-6:])` 
this should be the one-line alternative python command that do the same job

Answer (score 3):

So here are the ingredients for an approach that works using strings (simple but not the most efficient variant):

- `ord(x)` yields the number (i.e. essentially the bits) for a char (e.g. `ord('A')=65`). Note that `ord` expects really an byte-long character (no special signs such as € or similar...)
- `bin(x)[2:]` creates a string representing the number `x` in binary.

Thus, we can do (`mystr` holds your string):

```
l = [bin(ord(x))[2:] for x in mystr] # retrieve every character as binary number
bits = ""
for x in l:            # concatenate all bits
    bits = bits + l
bits[-50:]             # retrieve the last 50 bits
```

Note that this approach is surely not the most efficient one due to the heavy string operations that could be replaced by plain integer operations (using bit-shifts and such). However, it is the simplest variant that came to my mind.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I finally get a string from the last 50 bits?

Comment: Don't need a bit-shift, just a bitwise `AND` with the value `1` (binary `00000001`.) This will return `1` if the LSB is `1`, or `0` if the LSB is `0`.

Comment: @dciriello If you want the last 50 bits as a string, you note that 50=6*8+2. That is, 50 bits correspond to 6 chars and 2 single bits. Thus, you have to get the last 6 characters (`mystr[-6:]`) and from the seventh-last character (`mystr[-7]`) you have to get the last two bits and process them (`ord(mystr[-7]) & 0b11` extracts the 2 bits from the seventh-last character).

Answer (score 0):

If it's only to display, wouldn't it help you?

```
  yourString [14:63]
```

You can also use

```
  yourString [-50:]
```

For more information, see [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)