# Python - obtain least 4 significant bytes from SHA1 hash

Tags: python, string, hash, byte

I am trying to derive a function that will return least significant 4 bytes of a SHA1 hash.

For example, given the following SHA1 hash:

```
f552bfdca00b431eb0362ee5f638f0572c97475f (hex digest)
\xf5R\xbf\xdc\xa0\x0bC\x1e\xb06.\xe5\xf68\xf0W,\x97G_ (digest)
```

I need to derive a function that extracts the last significant 4 bytes from the hash and produces:

```
E456406 (hex)
239428614 (dec)
```

So far I have tried solutions as described in [Get the x Least Significant Bits from a String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903053/get-the-x-least-significant-bits-from-a-string-in-python) and [Reading least significant bits in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822130/reading-least-significant-bits-in-python).

However, the resulting value is not the same.

Comment: Unclear on your expected values. Wouldn't that least significant 4 bytes (8 hex characters) be `0x2c97475f`? How are you deriving your expected values?

Comment: These are the parameters that have been described as part of a blackbox function that I am trying to derive.

Comment: Q1) 4 bytes would be 8 hex characters. Is the hex value have a leading 0 (as in 0x0e456406)? Q2) Confirming you are looking for a function func(x) where func(sha1_hash) generates a value such that the last 4 bytes would be your target value?

Comment: Yes, the expected value is 0x0e456406 with a leading 0. And yes, given a SHA1 hash, I am looking at F(SHA1_hash) = 0x0e456406 for SHA1 f552bfdca00b431eb0362ee5f638f0572c97475f, where F returns least significant 4 bytes from that hash.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the least significant 4 bytes (8 hex characters) from a the sha1 value `f552bfdca00b431eb0362ee5f638f0572c97475f` use a binary mask:

```
sha1_value = 0xf552bfdca00b431eb0362ee5f638f0572c97475f
mask = 0xffffffff
least_four = sha1_value & mask  # 0x2c97475f
```